# Selenium is misclicking

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make Selenium click a button, Selenium has to scroll in order to click that button. But what happens is that when Selenium scrolls down, the button gets behind the sticky bar and Selenium clicks on the sticky bar instead of the button.

I'm using Firefox webdriver.

I tried the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX["elementScrollBehavior"] = 1
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

When I have `elementScrollBehavior` set to `1`, then it doesn't scroll at all.

How can I make Selenium scroll down properly so that the button doesn't get behind the sticky bar?

**-edit-**
`DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX["elementScrollBehavior"] = 1`

does work now, but it still isn't able to click on the button. Even tho the sticky bar doesn't get in the way now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somewebpage.example")
time.sleep(5)

while True:
    try:
        # Edit this to how you're currently scrolling
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 150);")
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, YOUR_BUTTON_XPATH)
        button.click()
        break
    except WebDriverException:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -100);")
        time.sleep(2)
```

If your script scrolls to far and throws an exception, it will catch this error and scroll back up the page 100 pixels.

This should guarantee your button gets clicked, it will constantly move 50px down the page until it finds it but you can implement your normal way of scrolling and then catch the `WebDriverException` and scroll back up a couple of pixels.

Comment: Right now: I have it like this http://pastebin.com/EVNiSF6P The selenium script is too fast is there another Selenium based alternative to `time.sleep()` I tried using implicit wait but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, you can the following to wait for an element to appear on the page.. for example after loading a page, to wait for the username field to show on the screen it will wait atleast 10 seconds unless the username element appears, then it will continue:
    username_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_id('username'))

Comment: the problem here is that it immediately clicks while it's scrolling,  due that I get `Element is not clickable at point (327.5, 15). Other element would receive the click`. So it doesn't manage to click because scrolling is not fast enough. It tries to click on the button while it's scrolling.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the element you're trying to click? if you scroll too far and there's something else on the screen covering it, the exception block should scrolll back up the slightly, enough to make it visible (which addresses: How can I make Selenium scroll down properly so that the button doesn't get behind the sticky bar?)

Comment: yes sry. There are plenty of things wrong like it clickes twice fast once on a radio button and the other on the button. Because of this it doesn't manage to click on the last button. I will fix this, your answer so far helped me alot so I will accept that one.

Comment: A simple time.sleep should make the script wait before clicking (this is what I use), although the WebDriverWait may be a better solution, if you can tailor it to suit your script.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use a javascript scroll to element then scroll a little more with an offset
eg in c#.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element)
jse.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,50)");
```

Comment: Maybe someone could convert this into python